# SQLCipher BLOB performance

Tags: ios, sqlite, blob

I'm currently running a database under iOS 6 with SQLCipher as encryption. Unfortunately I have to store some binary data (movies, large PDFs,...) in the DB. Right now I've created a table with just two columns: id and blob to store this data. But the more entries are added to this table, the slower the queries will become. Is there a way to increase the speed? Would the creation of one table per file maybe boost the performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using indexes on your tables and running queries that use those indexes? It sounds like you might be running queries that involve full scans. This is very expensive, even with standard SQLite, and even more so with SQLCipher.

Comment: the given table just exists of 2 columns: id and blob. An index on the blob column wouldn't affect performance, would it?

Comment: In general, yes. Is that the only table in your database? Are you performing lookups based on that id? If you are doing the lookup by the id value it will absolutely make a difference. Blob columns aren't stored separately, so if you search by id and an index is not used then the system must sort through all data for the table.